# How to use rabbitmq with microservices

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, microservices

I have three microservices Meal, Drink and Order. (with nodjs)

meal and drink microservices has GET(by id),PUT,POST endpoints and order contains only POST.

the idea of the project is that user is able to change the meal and drink until he press on make order button then order will be created.

**my problem:** is how to handle that with rabbitmq and I want to enqueue the meal and drink so order microservice can consume both but my problem is that user can update it

**my idea:** is in the create order I'll call to get meal and drink (by their microservice with http) so at this moment both values will in the queue

but really I don't like this idea as I feel I miss something and there is a better to do to get the most benefit of rabbitmq.

I'll be thankful for any better ideas.

Comment: What benefit are you trying to get from RabbitMQ? Why would you enqueue it before the user has finalized their order?

Comment: @daveNewton so you think my idea is good enough?

Comment: I just wished if I can enqueue and update in the queue when the user update it but this is not possible in rabbitmq

Comment: Why would you put it in a queue before it's finalized? It makes no sense--if, for example, the cook gets an order, if the order is changed in the middle of preparation it's now a pan of garbage.